# Is there any chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I've clicked on *chat* link, but the list is empty. Also I've tried to create one, but I couldn't, as it's saying:

> This room might already exist.

But it's not there yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a new [chat room for this site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/artificial-intelligence).

Seems like the one from the previous AI site prevented creating a chat room.